# Margin in RadioButton Image and Text in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I'm trying to create a radio button dynamically using .NET 3.5, C#. Here is the code:

```
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
radioButton.AutoSize = true;

radioButton.Text = "The majestic text that explored the world";
radioButton.Image = (Image)ResMgr.GetObject("get");

radioButton.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
radioButton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
radioButton.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
flowLayoutPanelSelectMonitor.Controls.Add(radioButton);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

There are several problems that I need to fix. Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

1. I need some margin between the image and the text. How can I set that?
2. I need radio button to resize so that the text appears in one line. How to do that without setting the width?
3. The image is clipped at the bottom. How to avoid that without setting the height?

Comment: Set the `AutoSize` property to `true`. Use `Popup` or `Flat` for `FlatStyle` property. If you want to perform custom rendering, you can use [`RadioButtonRenderer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobuttonrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Set AutoSize first to true, then store the width, set Autosize to false and set the new size with the stored width and the image.Height! For a Marging you can enlarge the image to include some empty space to its right.

Comment: Hmm. OK. There seems to be no good solution to this problem. I was expecting something automatic.

Comment: There is `TextImageRelation` property that can be set to `ImageBeforeText`.